# How to check if the device is connected to internet and Connection type in Harmony Os

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I was trying to check if the device is connected to internet and what is the network type. Here is an example of how we check it in android

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(Activity act){
        boolean isthere = false;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) act.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        if (tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN){
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) act.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if ((connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
                isthere = true;
        } else {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) act.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if ((connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED))
                isthere = true;
        }
        return isthere;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add permission ohos.permission.GET_NETWORK_INFO, which is used to obtain network information. Add permission ohos.permission.INTERNET, which is used to access the network.

•   Check if network is connected

```
public static boolean hasInternetConnection(Context context) {
        NetManager netManager = NetManager.getInstance(context);
        NetCapabilities netCapabilities = netManager.getNetCapabilities(netManager.getDefaultNet());
        return netCapabilities.hasCap(NetCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
}
```

•   Check if WiFi is connected

```
public static boolean isWifiConnectedInternet(Context context) {
       NetManager netManager = NetManager.getInstance(context);
       NetCapabilities netCapabilities = netManager.getNetCapabilities(netManager.getDefaultNet());
       return netCapabilities.hasCap(NetCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED) &&
                netCapabilities.hasBearer(NetCapabilities.BEARER_WIFI) ||
                netCapabilities.hasBearer(NetCapabilities.BEARER_WIFI_AWARE);
}
```

•   Check if Mobile network is connected

```
public static boolean isMobileConnectedInternet(Context context) {
        NetManager netManager = NetManager.getInstance(context);
        NetCapabilities netCapabilities = netManager.getNetCapabilities(netManager.getDefaultNet());
        return netCapabilities.hasCap(NetCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED) &&
                netCapabilities.hasBearer(NetCapabilities.BEARER_CELLULAR);
    }
```

Comment: How to do that in smart devices, so JS not Java?

Comment: @lacas Please refer to HarmonyOS JS API References of Network Management and Communications and Connections in https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/js-apis-overview-0000001056361791
 
For example: 
Network State: https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/js-apis-system-network-0000000000626092
 
WiFi: https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/js-apis-wlan-0000001121342036

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/connectivity-telephony-cellular-info-0000000000032143) to check the status of the connection to the Internet.

And the `TelephonyConstants.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE` can determine the network type.

```
// Obtain the RadioInfoManager object.
RadioInfoManager radioInfoManager = RadioInfoManager.getInstance(context);

// Obtain the signal information.
List<SignalInformation> signalList = radioInfoManager.getSignalInfoList(slotId);

// Check the size of the signal information list.
if (signalList.size() == 0) {
    return;
}
// Traverse the signal information list to obtain the signal information of the current network type.
LteSignalInformation lteSignal = null;
for (SignalInformation signal : signalList) {
    int signalNetworkType = signal.getNetworkType();
    if (signalNetworkType == TelephonyConstants.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE) {
        lteSignal = (LteSignalInformation) signal;
    }
}
// Obtain the signal strength of the specified RAT (methods in the child class).
int signalLevel = lteSignal != null ? lteSignal.getSignalLevel() : 0;
```

Comment: How to do that in smart devices, so JS not Java?